# A circuit/component which can reduce own resistance with increase of current

Tags: power-supply, component-selection

I'm trying to build following circuit for single-phase 230VAC grid:
0---(LOAD)---(MY_DC_CIRCUIT)---Phase

MY_DC_CIRCUIT doesn't have its own power source. The power is considered to be taken from the AC grid.
Following solution are feasible:

- Use inline transformer and rectifier. 1st coil connected in sequence with LOAD, 2nd coil rectified. Isolated, low heat - relatively good solution.
- Connect low Ohm resistor in sequence with LOAD. Rectify dropped on the resistor voltage. Non-isolated, heating - bad solution.

For both solutions bad things are:

- High load causes high heat.
- Low load generates low voltage.

Practical measurements confirm the theory: If LOAD runs 200 mA the MY_DC_CIRCUIT has 0.5V, 600mA --> 1.5V, 2A --> 5V.

I wonder if there is a circuit or electronic component that can be used in sequence with LOAD in AC grid that can adapt its own resistance to current.
In other words: A component that can reduce its resistance with increasing current.

Practical outcome of such component is:

- Same voltage can be on MY_DC_CIRCUIT no matter what current of LOAD.

P.S. I clearly understand that requested component for MY_DC_CIRCUIT must pass same current as LOAD.

Comment: How accurately do you need to keep the voltage drop constant? If the requirement isn't too strict, you probably want a zener diode.

Comment: If what you really want is to keep the voltage across the load constant then you want a linear regulator.

Comment: I thought about Zener, but couldn't imagine how to connect it. The voltage requirement isn't too strict: I can use voltage regulator or step-up/down converter deeper in MY_DC_CIRCUIT.

Comment: I'm having great difficulty in trying to understand this question. Are you asking for a constant voltage output with different loads. If so, what voltage do you want and what is range of current or load you expect?

Comment: Why does it have to be inline with the load? Why not use the transformer from solution 1 across the AC supply in the normal way?

Comment: Can you explain more what you want the circuit to do and less about how you are guessing it should be done? More about what the load requires, for example, will help us give you a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a "shunt regulator". The simplest shunt regulator is a simple zener diode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmaH1G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit functions as a voltage-limited halfwave rectifier. The drawback is that all of the load current (in both directions) flows through the zener diode, and it must be rated for this.

The first refinement we can make to this is to use a full-wave rectifier:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ3hor.png)</sup>

But while this doubles the current available to the circuit, it also doubles the dissipation of the zener. But we can use a power transistor to off-load most of that dissipation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc7dNu.png)</sup>

If the current gain of the transistor is, say, 50, then only 1/50 of the load current passes through the zener. The rest is handled by the transistor (which will probably need a hefty heatsink).

Now, if you need a truly isolated supply, then we can use the voltage-limited AC waveform at the AC terminals of the bridge rectifier to drive a 1:1 transformer, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr0RWA.png)</sup>

Comment: Dave, thank you very much. I tested all circuits and it just works. I found that there are ready shunt regulators but they aren't used for inline power draw. Can the bridge+zener be replaced with a single component?

Comment: I'm not aware of any single component, but you can use a pair of Zener diodes in series, back-to-back, to provide bidirectional voltage limiting, as long as they can handle the current. There are bidirectional TVS (transient voltage suppressor) devices, but their breakdown voltage generally has a very wide tolerance, and they aren't generally designed to handle continuous currents.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the maximal inline LOAD can be powered in this circuit is limited by transistor max collector current? If yes, can I replace it with FET to reduce heat?

Comment: No. In this type of circuit, the heat is determined by the product of the voltage and the current across the device, which will be the same with either type of transistor. I have seen dual-mode supplies used in devices like this, in which a voltage-based circuit like the ones shown above is used when the load current is low, but then they switch to using a current transformer when the load current is high. But the design of such a system is probably beyond the scope of an SE answer.